# Matplotlib: fill_between two curves using discrete points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate the following image:

[image]

So far I have written this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

yLow,yHigh = (-75,200)
xLow,xHigh = (-5.5,2.5)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = plt.gca()

x = np.linspace(xLow,xHigh,1000)
y = x**4
yG = -20*x +20

plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=1,linestyle='--',color='black');
plt.plot(x,yG,linewidth=3,);

plt.xlim(xLow,xHigh);
plt.ylim(yLow,yHigh);
# plt.xticks([], []);
# plt.yticks([], []);

plt.fill_between(x,yG,yHigh,alpha=0.3,color='green');
plt.fill_between(x,yG,yLow,alpha=0.3,color='green');
plt.fill_between(x,y,yG,color='red');
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now, I want to plot the grid of individual points and color them green or red as in the original image. I essentially want to fill_between with discrete points instead of complete shading. Is this possible?

Comment: You can define a grid and calculate the positions where the dots should have red and green color. Then plot a scatterplot with those positions as the color information. Once you get stuck with that you can ask a question about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I was able to accomplish this with a scatter plot and a meshgrid as:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,np.linspace(yLow,yHigh,numPoints));
Z = ( (Y<X**4) & (Y>-20*X +20) ) | ( (Y>X**4) & (Y<-20*X +20) );
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,cmap=ListedColormap(['green','red']),alpha=0.5);
```